# How to rotate the camera's bearing while await Future.wait, and stop it once complete in Flutter Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, flutter, async-await, future

I'm trying to achieve my customized loading animation in Google Maps for Flutter.

I have 3 HTTP posts (`shoppingFuture`, `diningFuture`, `transitFuture`) and have them added into a list of Future called futures

```
List<Future> futures = List<Future>();
futures.add(shoppingFuture);
futures.add(diningFuture);
futures.add(transitFuture);
```

Then I use a for loop to create `animateCamera` with `Future.delayed`. I further added them into the same futures list, just to see if the animation works

```
for (double i = 1; i < 360; i++) {
    futures.add(Future.delayed(
            Duration(milliseconds: 100 * i.toInt()),() {
               mapController.animateCamera(
                  CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
                     CameraPosition(
                         Target: LatLng(
                            urbern.lat, urbern.lng),
                         bearing: i,
                         zoom: 17,
                         tilt: 75)));
                        ));
}
```

Then I execute the await `Future.wait(futures)` for getting results from the 3 HTTP responses

```
var results = await Future.wait(futures);
var shopping = results[0];
var dining = results[1];
var transit = results[2];
```

It is kinda expected that I have to wait for 36 seconds for each run.

So my question here is whether there is a way to run two futures lists (one for HTTP posts/responses and another for `AnimateCamera` (ideally, it should loop), and once the HTTP posts/response is back or throws errors, the animateCamera stops.

I'm thinking `Future.doWhile` should solve my question, but I'm very new to Dart & Flutter

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented the above by implementing the VoidCallbacks `onCameraMove`, `onCameraIdle` in Google Maps for flutter